# Android: Debugging on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 in Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, debugging, device

My problem is: Eclipse doesn't see my device in AVD manager.
Mainly I followed the official android guide https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
I post steps which I did:

- **For the device Samsung Tab 10.1**:

  1. Declare your application as "debuggable" in your Android Manifest.
     In Eclipse, you can do this from the Application tab when viewing the Manifest (on the right side, set Debuggable to true). Otherwise, in the AndroidManifest.xml file, add android:debuggable="true" to the  element.
  2. Set up your device to allow installation of non-Market applications.
     On the device, go to Settings > Applications and enable Unknown sources (on an Android 4.0 device, the setting is located in Settings > Security).
  3. Turn on "USB Debugging" on your device.
     On the device, go to Settings > Applications > Development and enable USB debugging (on an Android 4.0 device, the setting is located in Settings > Developer options).
- **From command line**:

1)lsusb

```
    ....
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
    ....
```

2) sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

3) sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

4) ./adb devices

```
List of devices attached 
C4F12881C346B9E device
```

5) **Reset adb in Eclipse**

```
Window>> Show View >> Android (Might be found in the "Other" option)>>Devices

in the device Tab, click the down arrow, and choose reset adb
```

After the 5th step I receive an error in console from Eclipse

```
2013-12-20 19:37:49 - DeviceMonitor Connection attempts: 1
2013-12-20 19:44:22 - DeviceMonitor Adb connection Error:EOF
2013-12-20 19:44:22 - DeviceMonitor Connection attempts: 1
```

Can you help to solve the problem please?

Answer (score 1):

My USB 3.0 ports don't work with ADB!  Make sure you use a USB 2.0 Plug!

Also, make sure it's not a permissions issue:
$sudo adb kill-server
$sudo adb devices

--Tom

Comment: I was trying to debug in a vmware workstation on a usb3 Virtual USB device. When I changed to USB2.0 for the Virtual USB and rebooted it worked (The device has a USB-C connection so I assume it was working in USB3.0 Mode)

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Close the Eclipse if running
2. Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in terminal
3. type `./adb kill-server`
4. then type `./adb start-server`
   No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is started successfully.
   Now you can start Eclipse again.

it worked for me this way, Eclipse should be closed before issuing these commands.

Comment: DDMS uses a long-lived connection to the adb server running locally to get info about connected devices/emulators etc. The error message you posted generally just means that the connection to adb has been lost.
Because you ran the reset command, you essentially just killed and restarted an adb process, so Eclipse showed that harmless warning for a moment.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Tried ./adb kill-server after ./adb start-server. No error messages but still my device doesn't appear in AVD Manager... Any suggestions?

Comment: does adb list your device in terminal? type ./adb devices.

Comment: List of devices attached 
C4F12881C346B9E device

Comment: Still doesn't work... I've tried so many solutions, don't know what else to do!

Answer (score -1):

Select MainActivity.java tab and press RUN. After will appear a window choose a running Android device and press OK.

Comment: If adb doesn't see the device, then this solution won't help.